# Efficiently count zero elements in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to count the number of zero elements in `numpy` arrays. I'm aware of the [numpy.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) function, but there appears to be no analog for counting zero elements.

My arrays are not very large (typically less than 1E5 elements) but the operation is performed several millions of times.

Of course I could use `len(arr) - np.count_nonzero(arr)`, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Here's a MWE of how I do it currently:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

arrs = []
for _ in range(1000):
    arrs.append(np.random.randint(-5, 5, 10000))


def func1():
    for arr in arrs:
        zero_els = len(arr) - np.count_nonzero(arr)


print(timeit.timeit(func1, number=10))
```

Comment: `count_nonzero` is a very basic compiled operation.  Whether you want to know the number of zeros or the number of nonzeros, you still have to loop through the whole array.  Let numpy do that in compiled code and don't worry about efficiency.

Comment: Why do you think `len(arr) - np.count_nonzero(arr)`  is inefficient?

Comment: The difference between count_nonzero and a potential count_zero is one subtraction. This is about as efficient as you're going to get.

Comment: You realize that `len(are)` is a simple attribute lookup, right? It doesn't iterate the array again...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `len(arr)` is an attribute lookup through a  function call. Pure attribute lookup `a.size` takes 25% less time.

Comment: @DYZ yes, you should use `a.size` anyway, especially since `len(a)` will give the wrong answer for multidimensional arrays. But I don't think that is what OP was referring to...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A **2x** faster approach would be to just use [***`np.count_nonzero()`***](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) but with the *condition* as needed.

```
In [3]: arr
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 3],
      [3, 9, 0, 4]])

In [4]: np.count_nonzero(arr==0)
Out[4]: 2

In [5]:def func_cnt():
            for arr in arrs:
                zero_els = np.count_nonzero(arr==0)
                # here, it counts the frequency of zeroes actually
```

You can also use [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) but it's slower than [*`np.count_nonzero()`*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html)

```
In [6]: np.where( arr == 0)
Out[6]: (array([0, 1]), array([2, 2]))

In [7]: len(np.where( arr == 0))
Out[7]: 2
```

---

*Efficiency:* (in descending order)

```
In [8]: %timeit func_cnt()
10 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit func1()
10 loops, best of 3: 46.5 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit func_where()
10 loops, best of 3: 61.2 ms per loop
```

---

**more speedups with accelerators**

It is now possible to achieve more than ***3 orders of magnitude speed boost*** with the help of [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax) if you've access to accelerators (GPU/TPU). Another advantage of using JAX is that the NumPy code needs very little modification to make it JAX compatible. Below is a reproducible example:

```
In [1]: import jax.numpy as jnp
In [2]: from jax import jit

# set up inputs
In [3]: arrs = []
In [4]: for _ in range(1000):
   ...:     arrs.append(np.random.randint(-5, 5, 10000))

# JIT'd function that performs the counting task
In [5]: @jit
   ...: def func_cnt():
   ...:     for arr in arrs:
   ...:         zero_els = jnp.count_nonzero(arr==0)
```

---

```
# efficiency test
In [8]: %timeit func_cnt()
15.6 µs ± 391 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: `np.where` uses uses `np.count_nonzero` (at compiled level) to determine the size of the arrays that it returns.

Comment: Put it inside a function call for fair comparison... In this case I get 1ms instead of 160us for OP's method...

Comment: I've tried it, it is only marginally faster shaving less than ~10% of the time used by `func1`.

Comment: The new function is 2x faster than my original function. I think that's as good as it gets. Thank you!

Comment: On my computer with numpy version: 1.12.1 and 1000 arrays in the list, I get for func1: 1000 loops, best of 3: 376 µs per loop and func_cnt: 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop. So I am puzzled now.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same idea I had: I thought I'd try to use `zero_els = np.sum(arr == 0)`, but it is actually **slower** than any of the methods described above.

Comment: Yea, @plasmon360 - I seem to be getting the same thing; it makes sense to me that `len(arr) - np.count_nonzero(arr)` would be faster than `np.count_nonzero(arr == 0)` because you don't need to calculate the entire T/F array.

Comment: Using a function named 'count_**nonzero**' to count occurrences of **zeroes**. Good. Excellent. I would not change a thing here. This is good naming and makes sense.