# splitting an image into Spokes and calculate number of black pixels in each spoke

Tags: python, image-processing

In python, I am trying to separate an image into spokes and calculate the number of black pixels in each spoke. The end goal is to generate a sky-view factor of an image but any help on separating into Spokes (triangles of a circle around the center of an image) would be really appreciated.

For example I have an image captured with a fish eye lens a hemispherical image ( drawn example below) and i want to divide the circle image into triangles around the center (like spokes in  a wheel or pizza slices)

[circle divided into triangles like pizza slices or spokes around a wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehG4f.png)

The circle may not always be in the same place on the image and will not be divided into lines originally as it would be a hemispherical image of the sky. So as an example image would appear more like this:

[example of image with no division lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1smQB.png)

Regardless of where the circle is I would need the same number of segments e.g 8

Comment: What is a **Spoke** please? Do you have an image to share? What are the input and the outputs here? Please ensure there is enough information to allow someone to assist you. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updates the question, a spoke is a triangular section of a circle like a pizza slice or a wheel spoke

Comment: Do you have a couple more images please? Are the circles always in the same place and with the same number of segments, for example?

Comment: If you trim the black pixels off (see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132934 ) you will get a square. The radius and coordinates of the centre are half the width of the trimmed image. Now use PIl (Pillow - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/releasenotes/3.1.0.html?highlight=arc ) to draw an arc and mask off everything you're not interested in.

Comment: Thank you! Will try that

Comment: I meant `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.pieslice()` rather than `arc()`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got the time to do a full answer as I usually would, but I felt like contributing a few bits and bobs and no-one said answers need to be complete anyway.

**Step 1 - Trim black to find radius**

You can trim off the black pixels and get a square with the circle you want inscribed in the middle. You can do that using `numpy` to check if all elements in a row/column of the image/ndarray are zero and then slicing them off.

Or you can use [this method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132934).

Once you have a square, if you take half its width you will know the radius and also the centre coordinates of your circle.

[image]

**Step 2 - Generate masks**

Draw pie-slices to mask the pixels you want. I am drawing 3 slices here to demonstrate how to move around the circle, but you will just need one at a time.

Here is some code to draw the first few pie slices that can be used to mask the parts you want:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw,PIL.Image as Image, PIL.ImageShow as ImageShow 

im = Image.new("RGB", (400,400))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

sectors=8
angle=360/sectors

# Draw first sector bright white - fill colour is rgb(255,255,255)
startangle=-90
draw.pieslice((0,0,400,400),startangle,startangle+angle,fill=(255,255,255))

# Draw second sector slightly darker
startangle+=angle
draw.pieslice((0,0,400,400),startangle,startangle+angle,fill=(223,223,223))

# Draw third sector slightly darker still
startangle+=angle
draw.pieslice((0,0,400,400),startangle,startangle+angle,fill=(192,192,192))

im.show()
```

[image]

Obviously in your finished code, this step would be the start of a `for` loop over all eight slices and you would do one slice at a time.

**Step 3 - Apply masks**

So if you now take a mask image like this:

[image]

and invert (negate) it, then overlay it onto your original, choosing the lighter of the two images at each pixel location, you will get this (I have added a black border artificially afterwards so you can see the extent of it:

[image]

You can choose the brighter pixel with `numpy.maximum()` as shown [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html).

**Step 4 - Count desired pixels**

You can now hopefully count the black (i.e. zero-valued) pixels, or the white ones and subtract from the area of the whole shape.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42916378/2836621) shows a way. There are others.

Comment: Thank you very much this is all really helpful!!

Comment: This post shows you how to go from a PIL image to numpy array and back the other way https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091479/2836621