# numpy.sum with conditional

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code:

```
def compute_class_freqs():
    """
    Compute positive and negative frequences for each class.

    Returns:
        positive_frequencies (np.array): array of positive frequences for each
                                         class, size (num_classes)
        negative_frequencies (np.array): array of negative frequences for each
                                         class, size (num_classes)
    """
    ### START CODE HERE (REPLACE INSTANCES OF 'None' with your code) ###
    labels = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,1]]
    print(labels)
    # total number of patients (rows)
    N = labels[0]
    
    positive_frequencies = None
    negative_frequencies = None

    ### END CODE HERE ###
    return positive_frequencies, negative_frequencies
```

I want to sum the number of 1's in each row and append each sum to positive_frequencies, and sum the number of 0's in each row and append each sum to negative_frequencies. How can I do this using the numpy functions numpy.sum() and numpy.where()?

Edit: positive_frequencies should be the number of 1s in each column divided by the total number of rows and negative frequencies the number of 0s in each column divided by the total number of rows. Basically, the function should return numpy arrays of floats.

Comment: could you maybe provide an expected output please?

Comment: Here's your answer: [Efficiently count zero elements in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916330/efficiently-count-zero-elements-in-numpy-array) you can easily adapt it to your code (i.e. just pass `axis=0` to `count_nonzero`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work, i know there is already an answer in your comments and this doesn't use np.sum or np.where, but i thought i'd share how i'd do it without numpy:

```
labels = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,1]]

positive_frequencies = [len([num for num in listOfNums if num == 1])/len(listOfNums) for listOfNums in labels]
negative_frequencies = [len([num for num in listOfNums if num == 0])/len(listOfNums) for listOfNums in labels]

print(positive_frequencies, negative_frequencies)
```

Which got me an output of:

```
[1, 3, 2] [2, 0, 1]
```

However, if you want a numpy array from this you could try this:

```
import numpy as np

labels = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,1]]

positive_frequencies = np.fromiter([len([num for num in listOfNums if num == 1])/len(listOfNums)  for listOfNums in labels], dtype=np.float16)
negative_frequencies = np.fromiter([len([num for num in listOfNums if num == 0])/len(listOfNums)  for listOfNums in labels], dtype=np.float16)

print(positive_frequencies, negative_frequencies)
```

Comment: That's definitely one way to do it... though 1) it does not return numpy arrays as requested by the function; 2) it does not take advantage of numpy as requested by OP; 3) as a consequence of point 2 it is also a very slow solution.

Comment: positive_frequencies should be the number of 1s in each column divided by the total number of rows and negative frequencies the number of 0s in each column divided by the total number of rows. Basically, the function should return numpy arrays of float values

Comment: i changed the code to do what i believe you're asking for, and also added a numpy method